# $.get not working with phonegap cordovaExample

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, get

I have a problem with phonegap and `$.get` (jQuery). It's actually only a webapp which exists already but I want to bring it on my Android Smartphone.

So my `$.get` is working and I have this settings:

In `res/xml/config.xml`:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But it's not working :(

**Edit 1 (17.11.2013 15:23):**

```
alert("getData: "+searchTerm+" in "+language);
$.get("http://mysite.de/search.php", {art: searchTerm, lang: language}).done(function(data){
   alert("daten: "+data);
}, "html");
alert("ready");
```

Only the first and the third `alert` is working.

Comment: Check with Device's Internet connection

Comment: The smartphone is connect with the internet (WLan)

Comment: show us the code which doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mysite.de/search.php. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

You need to allow access to `http://mysite.de/search.php` from any domain

Allow it by adding code to your php page:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: I tried it `<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` and started my app but it's not working. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sth. like `$("#searchBar").keydown(function(event){`is working so can't be jquery.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41351/discussion-between-wikunia-and-vicky-gonsalves)